# Windows 10 camera window opens without initiating

Tags: windows-10, camera

Specs:
Intel Atom processor x64 SoC inbuilt with RAM DDR3 2GB, eMMC 32 GB and intel HD graphics
Windows 10pro x86 with original OEM license.

Windows is updated up to 20H2.

Problem:
The computer opens camera window without me clicking.

I have turned off my internet also to see if someone is remotely accessing my netbook but then also sometimes, the camera window show up with my camera turned on.

I searched for jpg and mov/mpg but no photos or videos of myself is there is this netbook.

Reason for asking the question:

I am scared if someone has trying to see what I’m doing. I have searched some bad sites and after that this happened.

I have not downloaded any softwares; just some videos.

There is no cracked apps too.

The only non Microsoft app is the Apache Open office.

Question:
Is someone watching me or is it any problem with Windows?

How can I know if someone is watching me?

Or should I reset my PC?

Comment: The camera should never turn on unless you invoke it. It is common for malware to surreptitiously turn on your webcam. Security experts often recommend putting a piece of tape over your webcam to physically block it if your computer should somehow become infected. I suggest running antivirus scans by several well-know antivirus products. See also [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: Yes, I scanned with Avast, it found many. So, I’m guessing it maybe any malware. But since there is nothing important in this pc, I did a full reset with removing everything. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: "found many" - I suggest formatting the disk and reinstalling Windows.

Comment: Isn’t the reset everything going to remove all the malwares?

Comment: Yes, but only if it's the kind that does NOT preserve existing files.

Comment: Yes, it doesn’t preserve any files. The problem with reinstalling is that if I install the latest OS using media creation tool, the audio doesn’t work. I would have to install the Windows 1903 and then have to update step by step. It will download 1903 updates. Then, update to each half yearly feature updates. This takes a lot of time but drivers will be compatible. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: You might be missing a driver. Search on the manufacturer's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this keeps happening even after reset and with no malware on your device, it means internal Windows app is doing it.

While there's low risk of privacy breach (they're not likely sending anything to anyone), it's still something better avoided.

Someone in a [Microsoft forum thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-camera-turning-itself-on/f62ba870-f58a-4235-b609-e5603356d76c) said that in their case it was WavesSysSvc process:

> I found out the application using my camera was WavesSysSvc. For some reason it was using my camera at those moments, so I ended it and disable it's startup. So far so good.

Might be your case as well, worth checking.

Comment: I will check it and update you. Thank you very much for the suggestion.